# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` . Well, I have object of array and I am extracting object keys but when I map a function then it give me error could someone please help me how to solve my problem . I tried but I failed I need to solve this application .

**Code**

```
 const patientTabOptions = {
    titleOptions: [
      { value: "mr", label: "Mr" },
      { value: "ms", label: "Ms" },
      { value: "doctor", label: "Doctor" }
    ],
    ageGroup: [
      { value: "infant", label: "Infant" },
      { value: "child", label: "Child" },
      { value: "adult", label: "Adult" }
    ],
    GenderOptions: [
      { value: "male", label: "Male" },
      { value: "female", label: "Female" },
      { value: "others", label: "Others" }
    ],
    bloodGroup: [
      { value: "a+", label: "A+" },
      { value: "a-", label: "A-" },
      { value: "b+", label: "B+" },
      { value: "b+", label: "B+" },
      { value: "b-", label: "B-" },
      { value: "o", label: "O" },
      { value: "o-", label: "O-" },
      { value: "ab+", label: "AB+" },
      { value: "ab-", label: "AB-" }
    ],
    maritalStatus: [
      { value: "single", label: "Single" },
      { value: "married", label: "Married" },
      { value: "notDisclosed", label: "Not Disclosed" }
    ]
  };

 let patientKeys = Object.keys(patientTabOptions);
```

In render function when I try to map it give me error

```
 patientTabOptions &&
                    patientTabOptions.patientKeys.map((item) =>
                      console.log(item)
                    )
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because the key `patientKeys` doesn't exist inside your `patientTabOptions` object.

If you want to iterate through your object's keys you have to use the variable you've created called `patientKeys`

```
patientTabOptions && patientKeys.map((item) => console.log(item))
```

Edit from comments :

```
patientTabOptions && Object.keys(patientTabOptions).map(key => patientTabOptions[key])
```

But if you want to get data from specific array you should access directly

```
const data = patientTabOptions.ageGroup
```

Comment: If my post helped you please consider upvoting and accepting as answer, thanks ! :)

Comment: well,it have still problem it return self keys . I want to access an array like patientTabOptions.ageGroup.map but here `ageGroup` will be achieve from `Object.keys(patientTabOptions)`

Comment: could you please help me ? I want to acheive my goal

Comment: You mean you want to access to your `ageGroup` array from `Object.keys(patientTabOptions).map()` ? Could you tell me data you want to extract exactly ? I can make and edit to help you

Comment: actually, I want to extract an array data . I want to access like that `patientTabOptions.Object.keys(patientTaboptions)`

Comment: I've edited my answer tell me if I misunderstood your needs